# Emacs autocomplete doesnt work properly

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete

I just started using Emacs.

I've Installed the autocomplete extension and the extension for c/c++ support.

The problem is that it shows hints only for the variables/functions etc. that are defined in the file it's open in the buffer. Is there a way to show all functions of the standard C libraries?

For example it should show all constants like

```
__LINE__
```

or

```
__DATE__
```

when I type __

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen people using `ac-source-semantic` and while it can be a
viable option, I don't use it because it's too slow.  On the other
hand, it's blindingly fast with the default sources.
`ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers` is especially good.

So I use `auto-complete` without semantic when I can get away with it.
If I can't, I call `moo-complete` from
[function-args](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args).

So it's your choice: you can either configure `ac-source-semantic`
or go with my approach.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. I just had to reinstall and configure emacs from scratch. The autocomplete package from the package-list command doesnt work properly, so i installed it manually again.